# VSCode CLI : Disable electron logging

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to not display this electron loggings on executing `code <path>` command ?

[image]

I prefer the CLI to not livetail this logging so that I can proceed with other command lines.
I cannot find article for this inside the CLI doc https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line.

Somehow it will do a livetail for the first time we use the `code <path>` command. The subsequent usage will not show the livetail.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71289#issuecomment-477481163), try running code.cmd in ~/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin, not Code.exe in the parent folder.